# Android - Keep incrementing delay before calling method until user stops interacting

Tags: android, synchronization, android-asynctask, delay, wait

I am using Google Maps V2, and need to call a method when ever the user moves the map. 
I am using .setOnCameraChangedListener() which fires every time the map is moved. From this event listener, i can call my method.

The problem is that, if user moves the map very slowly, the event is triggered multiple times within a second. The method I call from the event is however time consuming, and I don't want it to be called so frequently.

How can I maintain a timer that keeps pushing the delay say 300ms further until the user really stops interacting with the map. This way my method will be called after 300ms of the last time the event was triggered.

I've tried, synchronized, asyncTask (by using .cancel and .start over and over again), but nothing seems to work out quite well.

Answer (score 2):

Add the following as fields:

```
private Handler cameraChangeHandler = new Handler();
private Runnable throttledRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // code that should run when user interaction has stopped for 300ms
    }
};
```

Then do the following in your onCameraChange:

```
@Override
public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition cameraPosition) {
    cameraChangeHandler.removeCallbacks(throttledRunnable);
    cameraChangeHandler.postDelayed(throttledRunnable, 300);
}
```